# Адаптация под мобильные устройства

Tags: css

Сижу уже 4 часа голову ломаю , не получается и все , есть 2 картинки на главной странице сайта  их нужно оптимизировать под моб.устройства от минимального разрешения , скажем 200 px ширины до максимального скажем 978px

Вот мой код основной картинки , которая выводится на десктопе

```
.double_pick {
 background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/main_page/men.jpg);
display:block;
width:1365px;
height:410px;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
```

Вот мой @media запрос , под эту картинку

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px){
.double_pick {
background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/main_page/men.jpg);
max-width:100%;

}
  }
```

Я говорю браузеру чтобы он расширял мою картинку на 100% , от 1365 , а он мне выдает такое : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Половину картинку обрубает и все, мне надо чтобы полностью картинка в уменьшеном варианте отображалсь со стандартных моб.устройств(планшеты телефоны и т.д)

Оригинал картинки должен быть таким [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Please help

Comment: Нет, вы изменяете размер блока, а не картинки. А размер картинки в вашем случае меняется через background-size

Comment: @andreymal размер редактиуруется , только теперь почему то width начинает выпирать я указываю фиксированную шиирну background-size:50%;

Answer (score 1):

задайте блоку свойства

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px){
  .double_pick {
   width:100%;
   max-width:1365px;
   background-size:100%; или background-size:content;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Max_Manchak не работает, не фиксирует высоту и по ширине 1/3 от экрана

Comment: а есть какая нибудь ссылка посмотреть пример, может там совсем и не в картинке проблема?

Comment: @Max_Manchak да есть , https://spbsneaker.ru

Comment: @Max_Manchak к тому же еще height тоже барахлит , пытался сделать cover и contain всеравно не работает , то есть высота блока у меня выше чем высота background size

Comment: используйте следующий код представленный в примере http://jsfiddle.net/q4rma267/

Comment: но вообще по правильному в теге <a> стоило бы разместить тег <img> было бы меньше проблем и высота автоматом подстраивалась бы

Comment: блин огромное спасибо тебе ! слушай а что значит #page #main p a ?

Comment: это селектор который отвечает конкретно за стилизацию этих ссылок... единственный момент посмотри на других страницах или не поехала верстка..., на твоем месте я бы дал этим 2-м ссылкам какой нибудь 1 класс и стилизовал по нему чтобы не пересекаться с другими элементами страницы

Comment: @Max_Manchak да вроде все окей , а где мне стилизовать их классы, я просто даже не знаю откуда ты их вытащил, у меня класс был double_pick

Comment: например так http://jsfiddle.net/q4rma267/2/

Comment: @Max_Manchak тут вот еще что , нужно эти 2 блока поднять вверх, пытаюсь margin не помогает , не знаешь в чем беда ?

Comment: @Max_Manchak попытался их стилизовать не работает , опять все поплыло

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82383/discussion-between-max-manchak-and-alexander-kozin).